# Как объяснить Visual Studio, что юнит тесты с одинаковым именем, это разные тесты?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, google-test

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
namespace A
{
    TEST(Object, Serialization)
    {
        Object object;
        // ...
    }
}

namespace B
{
    TEST(Object, Serialization)
    {
        Object object;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Сборка двух таких тестов проходит корректно, потому что тесты имеют разные имена в связи с принадлежностью к разным пространствам имен. Однако, после сборки `Visual Studio` видит только тест из пространства имен `B`.

Это ненормальная ситуация. В крупном проекте может быть много типов с именем `Object`, которые находятся в разных пространствах имен. Что же, теперь при тестировании типов с одинаковым именем в рамках одного проекта для тестов нужно выдумывать дополнительные способы ручного декорирования имен тестов?

Существует ли способ решить эту проблему через задание специальной настройки при сборке в `cmake`?

Comment: Каким фреймворком тестирования вы пользуетесь? `Boost.Test` / `Google test` / `CTest` ... ?

Comment: Простите, забыл упомянуть. Использую Google Tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Макрос `TEST` принимает на вход два аргумента, задающие идентификатор теста, который затем будет использован при его авторегистрации:

1. имя тестового набора - должно быть глобально уникальным для разных наборов
2. имя теста - должно быть уникальным в пределах одного тестового набора

В приведенном коде два теста будут иметь совпадающие идентификаторы.